# Class method with begin transaction and return errors

Tags: php, object-oriented, mysql

I've created a method which is useful for executing multiple queries, and it works perfectly.  Is this a good way to handle this?

```
public function foo($rQuery)
{
    try {
        $this->done->beginTransaction();
        foreach($rQuery as $val) {
            $rSql = $this->done->prepare($val);
            $rSql->execute();
        }

        $commitCode = $this->done->commit();  
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        $errorInfo = "Ooops: ".$ex->getMessage();

        $roalBackCode = $this->done->rollBack();
    }

    return array('errorInfo' => $errorInfo, 'commitCode' => $commitCode, 'roalBackCode' => $roalBackCode);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is going to be a first, but *yes*. If I had to work on a project, and come across this code, I'd be happy. The only thing I'd change, perhaps, is the name of the PDO instance: `$this->done` doesn't say *I am a DB connection*, IMO. The catching of the exception is required here, but the fact that you're not re-throwing it, or throwing a new, more generic exception is debatable. I'll briefly explain why, but that's entirely up to you to decide

Other than that, I'd say you're pretty much on the money.
A couple of suggestions, though:

*Type-hinting*
You're *assuming* the user of your code will be so kind as to pass an array of strings to your function. He/she would have to look at your method to determine what arguments you're expecting. An easier way of doing this would be:

```
public function foo(array $queries)
{//this method clearly expects an array, pass something else, and it will crash
}
```

*Strings*
You're also assuming the array argument will be an array of strings, whereas there is *no guarantee* that'll be the case. If I were you, I'd do some checking/filtering:

```
$queries = array_filter($queries, 'is_string');
```

That will filter out any non-string elements from the argument array.

*Notice: undefined variables*
The array you're returning uses both the `$commitCode` and `$errorInfo` variables. Why? If the commitCode variable was set, then there will be no errorInfo. Include a return statement in the try block, or return `true`. If there was an error, *then* return the errorInfo.

```
return $this->db->commit();
//in catch:
return array('errorInfo' => $e->getMessage(), 'rollback' => $this->db->rollBack());
```

Or better still, *rethrow the exception* possibly contained within a more generic/custom exception object. The caller should be allowed to handle exceptions. *The caller should know what was passed to your method*, therefore any resulting exception is *his responsibility*:

```
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    throw new RuntimeException(
        'Not commited: '. $this->db->rollBack(),
        0,
        $e
    );
}
```

*Prepared statements, no binds*
Of course, this isn't your *actual* code, I take it, but you're creating prepared statements and then execute them with no (room for) binds.

If the query strings come from a trusted source, there's no need to create an instance of `PDOStatement`, IMO:

```
foreach($queries as $query)
{
    $this->db->exec($query);
}
```

will do, and it'll increase performance, too

*Allow binds*
You'll soon find this method lacking in usability, though. If I wanted to execute a number of `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ...` or `UPDATE` or `INSERT` or any query with parameters for that matter, I can't use your method.
Don't worry, though, for that's an easy fix:

```
public function foo(array $queries)
{
    try
    {
        foreach($queries as $query)
        {
            if (is_array($query))
            {
                $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query['prepare']);
                $stmt->execute($query['bind']);
            }
            else
            {
                if (is_string($query)) $this->db->exec($query);
            }
        }
        return $this->db->commit();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
         return array(
             'errorInfo' => $e->getMessage(),
             'rollbackCode' => $this->db->rollBack()
         );
    }
}
```

That way, I'm able to call this method like so:

```
$instance->foo(
    array(
        'SELECT * FROM someTable',
        array(
            'prepare' => 'SELECT * FROM anotherTable WHERE someField = :field',
            'bind'    => array(':field' => $val)
    )
);
```

Of course, this implementation still depends on the user being kind enough to pass the correct arrays to your method. If I were you, I'd create an *"Argument class"*:

```
class QueryArgument
{
    private $query = null;
    private $bind = null;
    public function __construct($query = null, array $bind = null)
    {
        if (is_array($query))
        {//allow user to pass array('prepare' => '', 'bind')
            $bind = isset($query['bind']) && is_array($query['bind']) ? $query['bind'] : null;
            $query  = isset($query['prepare']) ? $query['prepare'] : null;
        }
        $this->query = is_string($query) ? $query : null;
        $this->bind = null;
    }
    //this is just to make life easier
    public function getTransactionFormat()
    {
        if ($this->bind)
        {
            return array(
                'prepare' => $this->query,
                'bind'    => $this->bind
            );
        }
        return $this->query;
    }
    //implement getters and setters
    public function setBind(array $bind)
    {
        $this->bind = $bind;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getBind()
    {
        return $this->bind;
    }
}
```

Now you can use this like so:

```
public function foo(array $queryArgs)
{
    $queries = array_filter($queryArgs, array($this, 'filterQueries'));
    try
    {
        foreach($queries as $query)
        {//same as before
            if (is_array($query)) {/* ... */}
            else {/* ... */}
        }
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {}
}
//filter out only those elements that are instances of QueryArgument
//convert them to array or string
private function filterQueries($instance)
{

    if ($instance instanceof QueryArgument) return $instance->getTransactionFormat();
    return false;
}
```